# PHP, MySQL - Append to cell from input array, when ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've got a MySQL table, something like

```
sometable

id   |   val1   |   val2   |   val3
 1   |    ...   |    ...   |    ... 
 2   |    ...   |    ...   |    ... 
 3   |    ...   |    ...   |    ...
```

Where `val1` is set as a `UNIQUE` key.

I am inserting multiple rows simultaneously. The number is variable, and so the query is constructed in the following way:

```
for(...building array earlier in code...){
    $arr[] = array('val1' => $somVal[$i][0], 
                    'val2' => $somVal[$i][1], 
                    'val3' => $somVal[$i][2]);
}

$datafields = array('val1', 'val2', 'val3');

$insert_values = array();
$qms = array();

foreach($arr as $d){
    $qms[] = '('  . dbplaceholders('?', sizeof($d)) . ')';
    $insert_values = array_merge($insert_values, array_values($d));
}

$db = new PDO(...);
$db->beginTransaction();
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO sometable (' . implode(',', $datafields ) . ') 
                 VALUES ' . implode(',', $qms) . 
                 ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE val3 = "New Val3 Value"');

if($stmt->execute($insert_values)){
    $db->commit();
}
```

Where:

```
function dbplaceholders($text, $count=0, $separator=","){
    $result = array();
    if($count > 0){
        for($x=0; $x<$count; $x++){
            $result[] = $text;
        }
    }

    return implode($separator, $result);
}
```

And this works fine. When `val1` is a duplicate, the value in `val3` is changed to "New Val3 Value".

But this isn't quite what I want.

What I would like is for the new `val3` to be appended to the end of the current

Something like:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE val3 = val3 + ";" + $newVal3Val
```

But the problem is that `$newVal3Val` is buried inside of `$insert_values`.

How can I have the new `val3` appended to the current value, with semi-colon delimiter, when a duplicate is found?

Comment: Rather than positional `?` tokens, you could move towards named placeholders with the `PDOStatement::bindValue()` or `PDOStatement::bindParam()` methods.

Comment: and then the line would be `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE val3 = val3 + ";" + :newval3` ?

Comment: It looks like it might be better to make the val3 column a child table instead so you won't have to put multiple values in one column.

Comment: @Birrel Found a better solution, see my answer

Comment: @Don'tPanic yeah, I've pondered it, but there aren't any savings/benefits either way, for this particular purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values

> In an INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement, you can use the VALUES(col_name) function in the UPDATE clause to refer to column values from the INSERT portion of the statement. In other words, VALUES(col_name) in the UPDATE clause refers to the value of col_name that would be inserted, had no duplicate-key conflict occurred. This function is especially useful in multiple-row inserts. The VALUES() function is meaningful only in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause of INSERT statements and returns NULL otherwise.

You should be able to reference the values you've used in `$datafields` with the `values()` function

SQL: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE val3 = CONCAT_WS(';',val3,VALUES(val3))`

Comment: Yessum, that'll do it, exactly as you've written it out.